# Specify Position and Character in NVarChar Column

Tags: sql-server, select, character

I'm trying to perform a query for the number of records where the 11th character of a column is a 'G' or 'W', along with a date constraint, however am not having much luck. Here is what I'm trying:

```
SELECT * st_req_no, dt_order 
FROM shipment_info  
WHERE dt_order >= '10/01/2010' 
AND (SELECT CHARINDEX('G', st_req_no, 11) OR CHARINDEX('W', st_req_no, 11))) 
ORDER BY dt_order
```

Could someone please advise what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Could you show some sample data and the result you're getting when you run your query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Select * 
from shipment_info
where dt_order >= '10/01/2010'
    AND SUBSTRING(st_req_no, 11, 1) IN ('G', 'W')
order by dt_order
```

Comment: Thanks Cade and all. This worked like a charm...you're awesome! :-)

Answer (score -1):

```
Select      * st_req_no
            , dt_order 
from        shipment_info 

WHERE       (CHARINDEX('G',st_req_no,10) = 11 OR CHARINDEX('W',st_req_no,10) = 11)
        AND dt_order >= '10/01/2010' 

order by dt_order
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!